# OnePlus One device not shown in Eclipse (Ubuntu)

Tags: android, ubuntu, usb, oneplusone

I have turned my USB debugging mode and tried every setting for development purpose. The eclipse **does recognize other devices** but it's not working for **OnePlus One**. What are the steps required?

**Eclipse: 64bit**

Thanks!

Comment: Did you added rules for this device into 51-android.rules??

Comment: @PankajKumar No I haven't done it. what should be done? Tq for quick reply

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html, but it seems that Google does not provide a rule for OnePlus devices.

Comment: So what would be the solution to this? Would be very helpful @PankajKumar

Comment: You can go at https://onepluschina.wordpress.com/tag/adb-usb-drivers and download driver from here

Comment: @PankajKumar Solution for Ubuntu?

Comment: Not sure. Link has been blocked from my domain. So I have no much idea about that.

Comment: @Nabin : Don't need any drivers on Ubuntu. Just enable USB debugging mode from developer options.

Comment: @Nitish No I doesn't work. I have mentioned your suggestion on my very first line of the question. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in ubuntu.
Settings->Developer Options-->turn on Android Debugging.
Settings-->Storage-->menu on the upper right corner-->USB computer connection-->check box MTP/PTP

http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-one/help/phone-recognized-storage-connected-to-t2825728